# Hatched bars and standard deviation errors in bar charts with Matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar plot. On the x axis I have 4 different conditions: HFd, HFi, LFd, LFi. On the y axis Reaction time is displayed.

I need the bar representing HFd to be hatched and blue, HFi to be blue, LFd to be hatched and red, LFi to be red. In addition, I need the standard deviation to be displayed in black on each bar.
Here are my attempts. Although they work, they don't give me the bar plot I need. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
%% This code creates the plot, but without the standard deviation errors
and the different colours.

data1 = [228, 222, 229, 218];
sdev1 = [29, 30, 29, 31];
hold on;
figure;
bar(data1);
%errorbar(data1, sdev1); %it gives me a line that links the different standard deviation errors.
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',{'HFd', 'HFi', 'LFd', 'LFi'});
ylabel('Reaction time (ms)');
ylim([180 300]);



%% This code creates the plot, with different colours but without the hatched
patterns and the standard deviation errors.

dataHFdeg = [228, 0, 0, 0];
sdev11 = [29, 0, 0, 0]
dataHFid = [0, 222, 0, 0];
sdev12 = [0, 30, 0, 0]

dataLFdeg = [0, 0, 229, 0];
sdev13 = [0, 0, 29, 0]
dataLFid = [0, 0, 0, 218];
sdev14 = [0, 0, 0, 31]

bar(dataHFd,'b');
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',{'HFd', 'HFi', 'LFd', 'LFi'});
ylabel('Reaction time (ms)');
ylim([180 300]);
hold on;
bar(dataHFi, 'b');
hold on;
bar(dataLFd, 'r');
hold on;
bar(dataLFi, 'r');
```

UPDATE:

%% This code creates the plot, with different colours and with error bars, but without the hatched patterns

```
y = [228; 222; 229;218];                  %The data.
s = [29;30;29;31];                   %The standard deviation.
fHand = figure;
aHand = axes('parent', fHand);
hold(aHand, 'on')
bar(1, y(1), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'b'); 
bar(2, y(2), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'b'); 
bar(3, y(3), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'r'); 
bar(4, y(4), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', 'r'); 
colors = copper(numel(y) - 4); 
for i = 5:numel(y) 
bar(i, y(i), 'parent', aHand, 'facecolor', colors(i-4,:)); 
end
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:numel(y), 'XTickLabel', {'HFd','HFi','LFd','LFi'})
ylim([180 300]);
errorbar(y,s,'.');
```

%% To create for example the hatched pattern for the second bar - but it doesn't work

```
 applyhatch_pluscolor(bar(2,y(2)), '/', 1);
```

Comment: MATLAB doesn't have a ready function for creating hatched bars. Fortunately you can find some solution on the File Exchange: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/07/15/creating-hatched-patches/

Comment: @Amro, I have tried following your link. However, I still cannot create hatched bars. I have updated my question in order to see the new attempt. If anyone could help I would be very grateful.